# Search for certain keywords in all articles which cite a given article

Tags: citations, literature-search, google-scholar

I would like to search for certain keywords in all articles which cite a given article. Is this possible? For example using google scholar somehow?

I am new here. Please forgive me if this question does not fit to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google Scholar has the functionality that you are looking for.

First, find the article that you want other papers to cite on Google Scholar, then click on the *Cited by* link.

Now, click on the *Search within citing articles* box, and either type your keywords into the search field (you may need to enclose your keywords in "quotes") or do an *Advanced Scholar search* and type your keywords in the appropriate field(s) there.